# Error react when I run yarn start Type expected. TS1110

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

When I try to run yarn start I have always this error :

```
node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts(149,100):     
Type expected.  TS1110                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                              
    147 | ): match<Params> | null;                                                                                            
    148 |                                                                                                                     
  > 149 | export type ExtractRouteOptionalParam<T extends string, U = string | number | boolean> = T extends `${infer Param}?`
```

Comment: Enable `skipLibCheck` in your compiler options.

Comment: where ? in the package json file ?

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I have already "skipLibCheck": true in my tsconfig.json file

Comment: What's your TypeScript version?

Comment: "typescript": "^3.8.3",

Comment: and which version of `react-router` ?

Comment: I think your TS version is severely out of date... We're on 4.8 now. The parser in 3.8 might not understand newer TS.

Comment: "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"

Comment: And after change version I have this error : ./src/utils/index.ts                                                         
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')